# Escape not working in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Hi I'm new to AHK and struggling to find a working solution by searching

I'm writing a script to open a website which contains % in the url

```
#a:: Run, https://rsasdfx01/Reports/'%2fRVE'%2fV etc...
```

when I run this I get an error

The following variable name contains an illegal character: "2fRVE"

Given that I have escaped the % I don't understand why it is treating that string as a variable and what the issue is.

How can I make the command work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The default escape character is accent/backtick (`).](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm)

Your example is showing apostrophes!

Try this:

```
#a:: Run, https://rsasdfx01/Reports/`%2fRVE`%2fV
```

Comment: You could expand your answer by showing the use of an expression as an alternative to escaping: `Run,% "https://rsasdfx01/Reports/%2fRVE%2fV"`

Comment: Your comment here does the job nicely! Thanks